# Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+]

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, deep-learning, tflite, gridle

I am facing this Error while running tflite project a week ago it was perfectly but now i am facing this error i dont know why it happens

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\NEXGEN\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\tflite-1.1.2\android\build.gradle' line: 36

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':tflite'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I create a deep learning project in flutter it was running perfectly but now i am facing this error please give me guide about this